# Using named range as series values in Excel

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have a spreadsheet generated from a template using Apache POI with some Named Ranges hard coded in.

```
Named range: ACTUALS  Refers to: =Report!$O$5:$AL$5
```

Now I have a chart... one of the series looks like this

```
Series name: =Report!$N$5  Series values: =Report!$O$5:$AL$5
```

Notice the named range "refers to" is the same as the "series values".
Can I use the named range as the series value in some way similar to this?

```
Series name: =Report!$N$5  Series values: =ACTUALS
```

The section above gives an error so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, the sheet name must be included in the chart data range even if the named range is on the same sheet.  In your case: =Report!ACTUALS.